# accessing files after setup.py install

Tags: python, file, py2exe, setup.py

I'm developing a python application and have a question regarding coding it so that it still works after an user has installed it on his or her machine via setup.py install or similar.

In one of my files, I use the following:

```
file = "TestParser/View/MainWindow.ui"
cwd = os.getcwd()
argv_path = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
file_path = os.path.join(cwd, argv_path, file)
```

in order to get the path to `MainWindow.ui`, when I only know the path relative to the main script's location. This works regardless of from where I call the main script.

The issue is that after an user installs the application on his or her machine, the relative path is different, so this doesn't work. I could use `__file__`, but according to [this](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeEnvironment), py2exe doesn't have `__file__`.

Is there a standard way of achieving this? Or a better way?

EDIT:

Should I even worry about py2exe and just use `__file__`? I have no immediate plans to use py2exe, but I was hoping to learn the *proper* way of accessing files in this context.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something but why isn't your installer copying TestParser/* to the same location as everything else?  Relative paths should work regardless of where the application lives as long as all the paths are "relative" =)

Comment: @Dan McDougall I'm still learning about python's setup.py and friends, so I might be missing something, but scripts are installed in the bin directory, while the modules are stored under lib. So its the command line scripts that are stored separately from everything else. I assume that there is some standard way of setting up a project distribution of which I'm unaware.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219367/accessing-data-files-before-and-after-distutils-setuptools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With setup.py there is never a simple answer that works for all scenarios.  Setup.py is a huge PITA to get working with different installation procedures (e.g., "setup.py install", py2exe, py2app).

For example, in my app, I have this code to find files needed by the app:

```
def getHome():
  if hasattr(sys, "frozen"):
    if sys.platform == "darwin": # OS X
      return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(sys.executable)), "Resources")
    return os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
  else:
    return os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

"frozen" is set for apps created with py2exe and py2app.

So to answer your question, use `__file__` and do not worry about py2exe.  If you ever need to use py2exe, you will probably need to create a special case anyway.