# How to access data_files specified in setup.py during runtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I have created a setup.py for my python project to include a number of `.json` files during the packaging of my `.egg`. When I run the command `python setup.py install` I can see in the output as well as inspecting the `.egg` itself that the `.json` were included in the packaging.

Here is my setup.py

```py
setup(name='exmaple',
      version='0.0.1',
      author='nc',
      description='TBD',
      long_description=open('README.md').read(),
      packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests', 'examples']),
      data_files=[('json-configs', glob('json-configs/*.json'))],
      python_requires='~=3.0',
      install_requires=[
        'importlib_resources==1.0.2'
      ]
)
```

The issue I am having is around how to appropriately access these files during runtime of my python application. The `.json` files are configurations that need to be read in at runtime if the appropriate class is executed. I have been reading a lot about `package_data` and that seems to be the preferred approach, but I would strongly prefer to not have an `__init__.py` file in my `json-configs` folder for reasons outside of the scope of this question.

Is there a best practice for reading in `data_files` during execution? Is this not the use case for `data_files` and should I really only be using `package_data` with `importlib` to read in resource files? Are there other better alternatives to reading in resource files that need to be accessed during the execution of a python program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing data files before and after distutils/setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219367/accessing-data-files-before-and-after-distutils-setuptools)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+access+%22data_files%22

Answer (score 2):

It can be accessed through

```
import os
import sys

file_path = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'json-configs')
```